How to create a gradient background layer in MapboxGL?

Is there any way to create a gradient background in mapboxGL JS or Studio? There is a prop for linear gradient, but I can't find any information about polygonal gradient.
As a background layer or a polygon from -90 to 90.
Is there any way to create a gradient background in mapboxGL JS or Studio? There is a prop for linear gradient, but I can't find any information about polygonal gradient.
As a background layer or a polygon from -90 to 90.
Thanks!







map.on('load', function () {  
    // Add a source for the polygon area  
    map.addSource('gradient-source', {  
        'type': 'geojson',  
        'data': {  
            'type': 'FeatureCollection',  
            'features': [  
                {  
                    'type': 'Feature',  
                    'geometry': {  
                        'type': 'Polygon',  
                        'coordinates': [[  
                            [-180, -90],  
                            [180, -90],  
                            [180, 90],  
                            [-180, 90],  
                            [-180, -90]  
                        ]]  
                    }  
                }  
            ]  
        }  
    });  

    // Add the background layer with a gradient effect using multiple layers  
    const colors = ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff']; // Replace with your gradient colors  

    colors.forEach((color, index) => {  
        map.addLayer({  
            'id': `polygon-gradient-${index}`,  
            'type': 'fill',  
            'source': 'gradient-source',  
            'layout': {},  
            'paint': {  
                'fill-color': color,  
                'fill-opacity': 1 - (index / colors.length)
            }  
        });  

    });  

});  






// you can also crate a gradient image or use libriers likx D3.js


Nope, still a solid green color for me
